# Move items through lists

Tags: python

I have 3 lists and I wanna move items from one list to another. Everything works fine exept when I move an item to list 3. Then the program executes the moving step twice. Anyone got an idea how can I write this better and shorter?

```
from os import system

list_a = [2]
list_b = [1]
list_c = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

while True:
    system("clear")
    print "\nlist_a --->", list_a
    print "list_b -----> ", list_b
    print "list_c -----> ", list_c

    item = input ("\n?> ")

    place = [list_a, list_b, list_c]
    place_name = ["List_A", "List_B", "List_C"]

    for i, a in zip(place, place_name):
        if item in i:

            print "item", item, "--->", a
            print "\n\n1) List_A"
            print "2) List_B"
            print "3) List_c"
```

here seems to be a problem. when an item is moved to list_3 script does it twice

```
            target_list = input("move to ---> ")
            target_list = target_list - 1
            target_list = place[target_list]

            i.remove(item)
            target_list.append(item)

            print "\nitem moved!!"

            # break out of loop that was missing before
            break
    raw_input()
```

Comment: yes ,of course. sorry my fault. edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty simple. if you move the item to a later list in the iteration the for loop then continue iterating to that later list and see the item is now in that list and ask to move it again. Just but break at the end of the if statement. This will stop the for loop from iterating after the move has happened.

```
print "\nitem moved"
break
```

Comment: yes, that helped. But why this only appears when moving to list_c??